# Webscraping from a list of urls using ThreadPoolManager and Selenium

Tags: selenium, web-scraping, python-multithreading, threadpoolexecutor

I am trying to scrap flight prices using selenium from a list of urls. The list of urls I have is very large so my initial implementation that simply grabbed an element from from each url in iteration would take of 24 hours to complete. So I decided to take stab at speeding it up. I did some research and decided that using threading might help. The goal of the code below is to divide the urls between 3 threads, however, it is not working. I think the webpages might just not be loading? I am looking for advice in whether this is a feasible approach or not, or if it isn't what a better strategy might be. Thank you!

```
#import libraries
from time import time
import pandas as pd
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
from threading import current_thread
from threading import get_ident
from threading import get_native_id

## initialize drivers
driver0 = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe')
driver1 = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe')
driver2 = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe')

def get_cost(url):
    #use correct driver
    # print('url: ',url)
    thread = current_thread()
    print(f'Worker thread: name={thread.name}, idnet={get_ident()}, id={get_native_id()}')
    if thread.name == 'ThreadPoolExecutor-0_0':
        print('- Thread 0')
        driver = driver0.get(url)
    elif thread.name == 'ThreadPoolExecutor-0_1':
        print('- Thread 1')
        driver = driver1.get(url)
    elif thread.name == 'ThreadPoolExecutor-0_2':
        print('- Thread 2')
        driver = driver2.get(url)
    else:
        print("error")
    time.sleep(20) # maybe it doesnt have time to load?
    #find cost
    try:
        element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,'/html/body/c-wiz[2]/div/div[2]/c-wiz/div/c-wiz/c-wiz/div[2]/div[2]/ul[1]/li[1]/div/div[2]/div/div[9]/div[2]/span'))
        )
        cost = element.get_attribute('textContent')
    except:
        cost = "-"
    
    print('url: ',url)
    print('cost: ',cost)

urls = ['https://www.google.com/travel/flights?q=Flights%20to%20Paphos%20from%20Vienna%20on%202022-07-25%20one%20way',
        'https://www.google.com/travel/flights?q=Flights%20to%20Paphos%20from%20Vienna%20on%202022-07-26%20one%20way', 
        'https://www.google.com/travel/flights?q=Flights%20to%20Paphos%20from%20Vienna%20on%202022-07-27%20one%20way',
        'https://www.google.com/travel/flights?q=Flights%20to%20Paphos%20from%20Vienna%20on%202022-07-28%20one%20way',
        'https://www.google.com/travel/flights?q=Flights%20to%20Paphos%20from%20Vienna%20on%202022-07-29%20one%20way', 
        'https://www.google.com/travel/flights?q=Flights%20to%20Paphos%20from%20Vienna%20on%202022-07-30%20one%20way',
        'https://www.google.com/travel/flights?q=Flights%20to%20Paphos%20from%20Vienna%20on%202022-08-01%20one%20way',
        'https://www.google.com/travel/flights?q=Flights%20to%20Paphos%20from%20Vienna%20on%202022-08-02%20one%20way', 
        'https://www.google.com/travel/flights?q=Flights%20to%20Paphos%20from%20Vienna%20on%202022-08-03%20one%20way']


## MAIN
with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=3) as exe:
    exe.map(get_cost, urls)

## close drivers
driver0.quit()
driver1.quit()
driver2.quit()
```

Comment: get() method returns void... so driver = driver0.get(url) doesn't seem correct.

Answer (score 0):

I created a quick solution using [SeleniumBase](https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase) that runs with `pytest`, which already includes multithreading abilities:

`pytest test_scrape_google_flights.py -n 4 --headless`

```py
from parameterized import parameterized
from seleniumbase import BaseCase

class GoogleTests(BaseCase):
    @parameterized.expand(
        [
            ['https://www.google.com/travel/flights?q=Flights%20to%20Paphos%20from%20Vienna%20on%202022-07-25%20one%20way'],
            ['https://www.google.com/travel/flights?q=Flights%20to%20Paphos%20from%20Vienna%20on%202022-07-26%20one%20way'],
            ['https://www.google.com/travel/flights?q=Flights%20to%20Paphos%20from%20Vienna%20on%202022-07-27%20one%20way'],
            ['https://www.google.com/travel/flights?q=Flights%20to%20Paphos%20from%20Vienna%20on%202022-07-28%20one%20way'],
        ]
    )
    def test_parameterized_google_search(self, url):
        self.open(url)
        self.wait_for_text("$", 'div[role="main"]')
        content = self.get_text('div[role="main"]')
        items = content.split("\n")
        for item in items:
            if "$" in item:
                self._print("%s - %s\n" % (url.split(r"%20")[-3], item))
```

This was the result of running that:

```
pytest test_scrape_google_flights.py -n 4 --headless
=================================== test session starts ===================================
platform darwin -- Python 3.10.1, pytest-7.1.2, pluggy-1.0.0
rootdir: /Users/michael/github/SeleniumBase/examples, configfile: pytest.ini
plugins: html-2.0.1, xdist-2.5.0, forked-1.4.0, metadata-2.0.1, rerunfailures-10.2, ordering-0.6, cov-3.0.0, seleniumbase-3.2.9
gw0 [5] / gw1 [5] / gw2 [5] / gw3 [5]
2022-07-27 - $80
2022-07-27 - $235
2022-07-27 - $267
2022-07-27 - $216
2022-07-27 - $471
2022-07-27 - $516
2022-07-27 - $601
2022-07-27 - $626
2022-07-27 - $827
.2022-07-26 - Travel on Jul 27 for $80
2022-07-26 - $453
2022-07-26 - $515
2022-07-26 - $572
2022-07-26 - $596
2022-07-26 - $601
2022-07-26 - $314
2022-07-26 - $316
2022-07-26 - $480
.2022-07-28 - Travel on Jul 29 for $71
2022-07-28 - $96
2022-07-28 - $301
2022-07-28 - $616
2022-07-28 - $340
2022-07-28 - $347
2022-07-28 - $412
2022-07-28 - $462
2022-07-28 - $478
2022-07-28 - $669
2022-07-28 - $1,165
.2022-07-25 - Travel on Jul 27 for $80
2022-07-25 - $130
2022-07-25 - $422
2022-07-25 - $573
2022-07-25 - $615
2022-07-25 - $340
2022-07-25 - $384
2022-07-25 - $501
2022-07-25 - $646
```

(Full disclosure: I built that automation framework)

Comment: Do you mind clarifying how to run your example? I copied the code and installed parameterized and seleniumbase but there is no output when I run the code.

Comment: You might need the ``-s`` flag with ``pytest`` to see console output if you don't already have a ``pytest.ini`` file in the folder where you run the tests. This is the one I had: https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase/blob/master/examples/pytest.ini